# Going from <solution> to <exec program=msbuild> in NAnt

Tags: .net, msbuild, nant, projects-and-solutions

I've converted my app from .NET 1.1 to .NET 3.5 and unfortunately NAnt's  tag does not support .NET 3.5.  So I am trying to use the  tag to kick off msbuild directly.

Here is what I have for .NET 1.1:

```
<solution solutionfile="MyApp.sln" 
        configuration="ServerDebug" outputdir="MyApp\bin\ServerDebug">

             <assemblyfolders>
                   <include name="Dependencies\Libs\bin\ServerDebug"/>
             </assemblyfolders>
</solution>
```

I converted it to

```
<exec program="msbuild">
    <arg value="MyApp.sln /p:Configuration=ServerDebug;OutDir=bin\ServerDebug\" />
</exec>
```

So everything is working fine, except that I can't figure out how to replicate the really convinient  tag, which gives the compiler a hint as to where to look for dependecies.

What do i pass to msbuild to replicate the  functionality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it can be done with one of two options. Either by using **AdditionalLibPaths** or **AssemblySearchPaths**, which are described [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629394.aspx).

Something like the following:

```
<exec program="msbuild.exe">
    <arg line="/p:Configuration=ServerDebug"/>
    <arg line="/p:OutDir=bin\ServerDebug\" />
    <arg line="/p:AssemblySearchPaths=Dependencies\Libs\bin\ServerDebug" />
    <arg line="MyApp.sln" />
</exec>
```

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth, I was able to get NAnt 0.86 working with .NET 3.5 by adding the following to NAnt.exe.config. After doing so, this bit in my build file inside the `project` tag was all I needed.

```
<property name="nant.settings.currentframework" value="net-3.5" />
```

Added to NAnt.exe.config:

```
<framework 
    name="net-3.5"
    family="net"
    version="2.0"
    description="Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5"
    sdkdirectory="${path::combine(sdkInstallRoot, 'bin')}"
    frameworkdirectory="${path::combine(installRoot, 'v3.5')}"
    frameworkassemblydirectory="${path::combine(installRoot, 'v2.0.50727')}"
    clrversion="2.0.50727"
    >
    <runtime>
        <probing-paths>
            <directory name="lib/net/2.0" />
            <directory name="lib/net/neutral" />
            <directory name="lib/common/2.0" />
            <directory name="lib/common/neutral" />
        </probing-paths>
        <modes>
            <strict>
                <environment>
                    <variable name="COMPLUS_VERSION" value="v2.0.50727" />
                </environment>
            </strict>
        </modes>
    </runtime>
    <reference-assemblies basedir="${path::combine(installRoot, 'v2.0.50727')}">
        <include name="Accessibility.dll" />
        <include name="mscorlib.dll" />
        <include name="Microsoft.Build.Utilities.dll" />
        <include name="Microsoft.Vsa.dll" />
        <include name="Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll" />
        <include name="Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.dll" />
        <include name="Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.Data.dll" />
        <include name="System.Configuration.dll" />
        <include name="System.Configuration.Install.dll" />
        <include name="System.Data.dll" />
        <include name="System.Data.OracleClient.dll" />
        <include name="System.Data.SqlXml.dll" />
        <include name="System.Deployment.dll" />
        <include name="System.Design.dll" />
        <include name="System.DirectoryServices.dll" />
        <include name="System.dll" />
        <include name="System.Drawing.Design.dll" />
        <include name="System.Drawing.dll" />
        <include name="System.EnterpriseServices.dll" />
        <include name="System.Management.dll" />
        <include name="System.Messaging.dll" />
        <include name="System.Runtime.Remoting.dll" />
        <include name="System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.dll" />
        <include name="System.Security.dll" />
        <include name="System.ServiceProcess.dll" />
        <include name="System.Transactions.dll" />
        <include name="System.Web.dll" />
        <include name="System.Web.Mobile.dll" />
        <include name="System.Web.RegularExpressions.dll" />
        <include name="System.Web.Services.dll" />
        <include name="System.Windows.Forms.dll" />
        <include name="System.Xml.dll" />
    </reference-assemblies>
    <reference-assemblies basedir="${environment::get-folder-path('ProgramFiles')}/Reference Assemblies/Microsoft/Framework/v3.5">
        <include name="Microsoft.Build.Engine.dll" />
        <include name="Microsoft.Build.Framework.dll" />
        <include name="System.AddIn.Contract.dll" />
        <include name="System.AddIn.dll" />
        <include name="System.Core.dll" />
        <include name="System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" />
        <include name="System.Data.Linq.dll" />
        <include name="System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.dll" />
        <include name="System.Management.Instrumentation.dll" />
        <include name="System.Net.dll" />
        <include name="System.ServiceModel.Web.dll" />
        <include name="System.Web.Extensions.Design.dll" />
        <include name="System.Web.Extensions.dll" />
        <include name="System.Windows.Presentation.dll" />
        <include name="System.WorkflowServices.dll" />
        <include name="System.Xml.Linq.dll" />
    </reference-assemblies>
    <reference-assemblies basedir="${environment::get-folder-path('ProgramFiles')}/Reference Assemblies/Microsoft/Framework/v3.0">
        <include name="System.IdentityModel.dll" />
        <include name="System.IdentityModel.Selectors.dll" />
        <include name="System.IO.Log.dll" />
        <include name="System.Printing.dll" />
        <include name="System.Runtime.Serialization.dll" />
        <include name="System.ServiceModel.dll" />
        <include name="System.Speech.dll" />
        <include name="System.Workflow.Activities.dll" />
        <include name="System.Workflow.ComponentModel.dll" />
        <include name="System.Workflow.Runtime.dll" />
        <include name="WindowsBase.dll" />
    </reference-assemblies>
    <task-assemblies>
        <!-- include MS.NET version-neutral assemblies -->
        <include name="extensions/net/neutral/**/*.dll" />
        <!-- include MS.NET 2.0 specific assemblies -->
        <include name="extensions/net/2.0/**/*.dll" />
        <!-- include MS.NET specific task assembly -->
        <include name="NAnt.MSNetTasks.dll" />
        <!-- include MS.NET specific test assembly -->
        <include name="NAnt.MSNet.Tests.dll" />
        <!-- include .NET 2.0 specific assemblies -->
        <include name="extensions/common/2.0/**/*.dll" />
    </task-assemblies>
    <tool-paths>
        <directory name="${path::combine(sdkInstallRoot, 'bin')}" />
        <directory name="${path::combine(installRoot, 'v3.5')}" />
        <directory name="${path::combine(installRoot, 'v2.0.50727')}" />
    </tool-paths>
    <project>
        <readregistry
            property="installRoot"
            key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\InstallRoot"
            hive="LocalMachine" />
        <readregistry
            property="sdkInstallRoot"
            key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.1\WinSDKNetFxTools\InstallationFolder"
            hive="LocalMachine"
            failonerror="false" />
        <property name="frameworkDirectoryV35" value="${path::combine(installRoot, 'v3.5')}" />
        <fail if="${not(directory::exists(frameworkDirectoryV35))}">The Framework directory for .NET 3.5 does not exist.</fail>
        <property name="referenceV35" value="${environment::get-folder-path('ProgramFiles')}/Reference Assemblies/Microsoft/Framework/v3.5" />
        <fail if="${not(directory::exists(referenceV35))}">The Reference Assemblies directory for .NET 3.5 does not exist.</fail>
    </project>
    <tasks>
        <task name="csc">
            <attribute name="exename">${path::combine(frameworkDirectoryV35,'csc.exe')}</attribute>
            <attribute name="supportsnowarnlist">true</attribute>
            <attribute name="supportswarnaserrorlist">true</attribute>
            <attribute name="supportskeycontainer">true</attribute>
            <attribute name="supportskeyfile">true</attribute>
            <attribute name="supportsdelaysign">true</attribute>
            <attribute name="supportsplatform">true</attribute>
            <attribute name="supportslangversion">true</attribute>
        </task>
        <task name="vbc">
            <attribute name="exename">${path::combine(frameworkDirectoryV35,'vbc.exe')}</attribute>
            <attribute name="supportsdocgeneration">true</attribute>
            <attribute name="supportsnostdlib">true</attribute>
            <attribute name="supportsnowarnlist">true</attribute>
            <attribute name="supportskeycontainer">true</attribute>
            <attribute name="supportskeyfile">true</attribute>
            <attribute name="supportsdelaysign">true</attribute>
            <attribute name="supportsplatform">true</attribute>
            <attribute name="supportswarnaserrorlist">true</attribute>
        </task>
        <task name="jsc">
            <attribute name="supportsplatform">true</attribute>
        </task>
        <task name="vjc">
            <attribute name="supportsnowarnlist">true</attribute>
            <attribute name="supportskeycontainer">true</attribute>
            <attribute name="supportskeyfile">true</attribute>
            <attribute name="supportsdelaysign">true</attribute>
        </task>
        <task name="resgen">
            <attribute name="supportsassemblyreferences">true</attribute>
            <attribute name="supportsexternalfilereferences">true</attribute>
        </task>
        <task name="al">
            <attribute name="exename">${path::combine(sdkInstallRoot, 'bin/al.exe')}</attribute>
        </task>
        <task name="delay-sign">
            <attribute name="exename">sn</attribute>
        </task>
        <task name="license">
            <attribute name="exename">lc</attribute>
            <attribute name="supportsassemblyreferences">true</attribute>
        </task>
    </tasks>
</framework>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have doing configuration management with Nant and CC.Net for a while now. I my experience I would not recommed using the Nant MSBuild task, instead the easiest way is creating and  task, create a .bat file that the task executes.  There are several reasons that would recommend using the command line Visual Studio, for one MSI packages are not easily build with Nant, even if you use contrib. Its just way easier and a lot faster this way.

---------2.0 -------------
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\devenv" C:\YourProject\YourSoultion.sln /Rebuild release

----------3.5--------------
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv" C:\YourProject\YourSoultion.sln /Rebuild release

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to call MSBuild in the batch file?

Comment: Devenv, does reference MSBuild to build the sln files. There are some subtle difference between just invoking MSbuild Vs going with Devenv. Our dev team is on VS 2008 and invoking Devenv command line basically produces the exact same output that our dev team would produce. That is my reason for choosing it over just invoking MSbuild, that way if something breaks we know we are comparing apples to apples and can at least eliminate build environment. Devenv would be a little slower though compare to just invoking Msbuild, but usually not by much.

Comment: Devenv requires an install of Visual Studio on the build server however. For licence reasons (and simplicity) a lot of build servers just have the Framework installed, which is all that is needed to build the projects. Assuming you avoid Setup and Web Deployment projects, which should be avoided for many reasons anyway and use alternatives that don't depend on Visual Studio to build.