# How to specify MSBuild version in nant script?

Tags: msbuild, nant, msbuild-4.0

I have a nant script that in one of its targets uses the msbuild tags to build a Visual Studio 2010 solution.

The problem is it fails when it hits this point, the error is:

```
Solution file error MSB5014: File format version is not recognized.  MSBuild can only read solution files between versions 7.0 and 9.0, inclusive.

Failed to start MSBuild.

External Program Failed:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\msbuild.exe (return code was 1)
```

The error makes sense, if it's calling the .NET 2.0 version of MSBuild it won't compile the VS2010 solution.  However, I can't figure out how to get it to call the right version of MSBuild.

If I run 'where MSBuild' (from the same VS2010 Command Prompt that the build script failed in), I get:

```
 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe
 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\MSBuild.exe
```

If I run 'msbuild /version' (again, same window) I get:

```
 Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 4.0.30319.17929
 [Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.18034]
 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

 4.0.30319.17929
```

So everything looks like it should be using the 4.0 version, but it's not.  Any idea what gives?  I know I've addressed this issue before, but can't remember what it was to save my life.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I appreciate the answers, and I know skolima's would work, the solution ended up being as simple as the addition of this tag:

```
    <property name="nant.settings.currentframework" value="net-3.5"/>
```

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Older versions of NAnt/NAntContrib default to v2.0.

Sounds like: [Nant msbuild task with .net 4.0 rc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353404/nant-msbuild-task-with-net-4-0-rc)

Answer (score 1):

What I usually use is I execute `NAnt`  with `-t:net-4.0` switch (or any other framework version) and in my script I would have [`<exec program="${framework::get-tool-path('msbuild.exe')}" managed="strict" />`](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/functions/framework.get-tool-path%28System.String%29.html) to actually invoke msbuild. Yes, this doesn't use the built-in [`<msbuild/>`](http://nantcontrib.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/msbuild.html) task but is more resilient.

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar question: [<msbuild> task or msbuild.exe with NAnt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195389/msbuild-task-or-msbuild-exe-with-nant/1202121#1202121) a while back

Essentially, if you set a property that points to the MSBuild executable, you can avert the (long term) issue when you upgrade to a newer of .NET than what NAnt supports out ofthe box.